# Spring Redisson Sentinel Error - At least two sentinels are required

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel, redisson

I am using Sentinel mode for Redis. I am using Redisson Client version 3.9.1

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-20</artifactId>
        <version>${redisson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>${redisson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The configuration of Sentinel using Redisson:

```
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCache {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient redissonClient() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setCodec(new JsonJacksonCodec(objectMapper));

        config.useSentinelServers()
                    .setMasterName("redis-master")
                    .addSentinelAddress("redis://localhost:26378")
                    .addSentinelAddress("redis://localhost:26379");

        return Redisson.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedissonConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redisson) {
        return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redisson);
    }
}
```

I am running two sentinel servers and one Redis master with no slave.
This is just a setup on my local environment.
Output of some commands:

```
redis-cli -p 26379
127.0.0.1:26379> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name redis-master
1) "127.0.0.1"
2) "6379"
redis-cli -p 26378
127.0.0.1:26378> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name redis-master
1) "127.0.0.1"
2) "6379"
```

Whenever I am running my Spring Boot Application, I get the following error:

```
       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonClient' defined in class path resource [xxxx/cache/impl/redis/config/RedisCache.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redissonClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: At least two sentinels should be defined in Redis configuration!

......

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init> (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup (TomcatStarter.java:54)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal (StandardContext.java:5245)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1420)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1410)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 22.566 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-07T13:44:14+05:30
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project xxx: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [xxxxxxx/cache/impl/redis/config/RedisCache.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redissonConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonClient' defined in class path resource [xxxxxx/cache/impl/redis/config/RedisCache.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redissonClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: At least two sentinels should be defined in Redis configuration!
```

How do I resolve this error?

PS: I have tried master-slave configuration also, with one sentinel attached to the host and other one attached to the slave, but the error remains the same. I have tried sentinels running on different local machines with different private IPs, but the error remains the same.
Tried with 3 sentinel servers, no benefits.

Comment: .addSentinelAddress("redis://localhost:26379")
                    .addSentinelAddress("redis://localhost:26379"); both lines are same..change 2nd line port to 26378

Comment: that's a typo in posting the question, I tried using different ports, different formats like - localhost:26379, 127.0.0.1:26379, redis://127.0.0.1:26379, none works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redisson doesn't seem to be working with localhost addresses. When I replaced the sentinel nodes addresses with the ones hosted on AWS, it worked fine.

Redisson, in my opinion, is a very immature client. Consider using lettuce or jedis.

See the bug filed at https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1736
which doesn't allow it to shut down.

Most of the problems I faced were when I used the sentinel mode. Cluster mode I have not tried. Works fine in single mode.

Also, they don't cater to bugs or issues filed on github for months which is obvious as they have a pro and paid version, so you are on your own.

I won't recommend using Redisson as of now.

Comment: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1736 issue already fixed in 2.15.0 / 3.10.0 versions.

Comment: great to hear, would have been great if you can cater to issues on github first and then on SO.

Comment: The problem on not working with localhost addresses does not seems to be sorted yet. It works for the ones hosted in AWS, but not with localhost, in fact the setting they suggest checkSentinelsList=false does not has expected behavior when its localhost

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run both `redis-server` as well as `redis-sentinal <config>`.
Once done, check which port sentinal is running at. It could also be 5000, it was in my case. Then pass `"redis://localhost:5000"` to `addSentinelAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `checkSentinelsList = false` setting.